# discord.py "error.retry_after" returns a float; I want it in hour:minute:second format

Tags: python, discord.py

My code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(message, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await message.channel.send(f'This command is not ready to use, try again in  %.2f seconds' % error.retry_after)
```

Output: `This command is not ready to use, try again in  43193.02 seconds`

Instead of "43193.02 seconds" how do i format it to make it say "try again in hour:minute:second"?

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        remaining_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(error.retry_after)))

        embed = discord.Embed(title=":clock1: Slow Down!!", description=f'{ctx.author.mention}, you can use this command again in ' + str(remaining_time), color=0xE74C3C)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

You can use the datetime import to split the seconds, minutes and hours like above.

Make sure to import datetime